# Returning Time with correct timezone offset from SQL Server to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, datetime

I have a datetimeoffset field in a SQL Server table that stores datetimes from a variety of timezones. Here is an example

```
2015-02-05 21:43:20.7660000 +13:00
```

Using the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (version 3.2.0) gem, I connect to this SQL Server instance and query the table. When I get a result, it seems the offset is being stripped and set to either UTC or local time. Here is an example

```
> Event.maximum(:timestamp_of_event)
=> 2015-02-05 21:43:20 UTC
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone` is set to `:utc` and I can set it to `:local` but really I want `:whatever_is_stored_in_the_table`.

How can I get the adapter to read in the offset as stored in the database? Is this possible? Or maybe I could define the type of this column as string and do the parsing all in code?

Comment: The best I have so far is some code that will add an offset back in: `DateTime.parse(Event.maximum(:timestamp_of_event).to_s).change(offset: ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone_of_event].formatted_offset(false))`

Comment: Even better than above, using the handy `_before_type_cast` methods (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html): `record = Event.where(conditions).order('timestamp_of_event DESC').limit(1).first; record.nil? ? nil : record.read_attribute_before_type_cast('timestamp_of_event')` which will return a string that can be parsed by `DateTime.parse`